# Dell XPS 15 9570 with multiple drives

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 that has two drivers. 1st drive has just Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The 2nd drive has both Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10.

When the computer boots up, I want to be able to choose the drive.
If I choose the first drive, it should bring up the GRUB menu so I can select Windows or Ubuntu. If I chose the second drive, it should select Ubuntu (it's the only OS on that drive).

How do I configure my laptop so it does this?

In my BIOS, the boot sequence lists two entries:

1. ubuntu                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
2. Windows Boot Manager      \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi

Thx

Comment: the BIOS lets the bootloaders handle that.  Currently your boot loader is GRUB.  Your BIOS does not typically give you the pretty graphical prompt of which to boot to - either GRUB or the Windows boot loader to.

Comment: On a Dell, you can start up with F12 pressed, which then allows you to select which device to boot. The more obvious approach, however, is simply have grub offer you the option which of the installed operating systems to boot for the day.

Comment: When I press F12 on startup, it only lists partition 1 of the 2nd drive.